# How to match multiple substrings splitted by a character?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, substring

Say I have the following string: `aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.eee`. I want to split this string by the `.` character at each occurrence, except the last occurrence. In other words, I want my result to be the following:

```
[
    "aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.eee",
    "bbb.ccc.ddd.eee",
    "ccc.ddd.eee",
    "ddd.eee"
]
```

I can only achieve this with **multiple** explicit loops but I wanted to avoid that, if possible. I'm no JavaScript master and maybe there's some function I'm not aware of, that could help. Making the final solution shorter and simpler.

Comment: I can't think of a built-in way to do this, I think you'll have to write a loop. If you don't like writing loops, you won't go far as a programmer, it's an everyday activity.

Comment: Seriously? I even had the `multiple` word in bold...

Comment: Didn't really notice that qualifier, but multiple and nested loops are not uncommon. Although probably not needed for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to so this, but here is one with a single loop:

```
function splitAndJoin(val) {
    var retVal = [];
    val = val.split('.');

    while(val.length > 1) {
        retVal.push(val.join('.'));
        val.shift();
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Usage:

```
splitAndJoin('aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.eee')
```

Result:

```
[
  "aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.eee",
  "bbb.ccc.ddd.eee",
  "ccc.ddd.eee",
  "ddd.eee"
]
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o1mkkwt7/)

Comment: The kind of solution that I was looking for. I actually had something like this but I was using a loop inside another one, which felt really stupid but I wasn't able to fix it. Long work day I guess. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A *single* loop should suffice:

```
var string = "aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.eee",
    result = [],
    regex = /[^.]*\./g,
    m;
while (m = regex.exec(string))
    result.push(string.slice(m.index));
```

However, I think using regex is total overkill for this, and using the standard [string `split` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) should suffice. By using [array iteration methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods), you even get around writing *explicit loops*:

```
var string = "aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.eee";
return string.split(".") // ["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee"]
.map(function(_, i, parts) { // for each index
    return parts.slice(i); // make an array with a different length
}).filter(function(p) {
    return p.length >= 2; // take only the arrays with at least two parts
}).map(function(p) {
    return p.join("."); // make a string from each of those arrays
});
```

As @dc5 said, there are multiple ways to do it. You probably had used multiple (nested) loops because you did not know of the [Array `slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) methods which of course internally do loop over the array.